# Disable TLS Handshake Client Certificate Request in Service Fabric Application

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, azure-service-fabric

I'm creating a web service in Azure Service Fabric and running on Docker containers on .net Core 2.0. The service is meant to be called by clients that aren't able to provide a client certificate for a mutual TLS authentication handshake, however, my service is prompting for this certificate, which is causing the clients to reset the connection and not get the response from the service.

In my setup code, I'm running this netsh command to bind the SSL cert to port 443:

```
netsh.exe http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=E362F4AB1FC4227F3010952876B505D510B0F6AA appid={8e6ea06d-b92f-4d99-911a-3c68de243eb4} verifyclientcertrevocation=enable clientcertnegotiation=disable'
```

That completes successfully and the binding is established, but when clients call the service (or when I try to call from a browser or Fiddler/Postman) I get a request for the client certificate still. From looking at documentation, the "clientcertnegotiation" parameter is the relevant piece here, and as I understand it should be disabled to remove the client certificate prompt.

Clients are able to successfully call the service without a connection reset when they call with a redirect through Fiddler.

I'm not sure if there's something incorrectly configured on the SF cluster side, so I looked into the configuration there as well. I found a security property called "ProtectionLevel" that was set to "EncryptAndSign". Searching for some information on this, I found this page on Microsoft's docs: [Understanding Protection Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/understanding-protection-level).

I'm not sure I'm parsing the information on that page correctly, but I thought it might be related, so I did a test in a development environment to see whether I would get the prompt if I set "ProtectionLevel" to "None", but I was still prompted for the certificate.

I also am using CORS, though I doubt that has anything to do with the mutual TLS configuration, and I got the same behavior whether CORS was enabled or not.

Are there any other Service Fabric or application-level settings that would be overriding my SSL binding configuration? Is Service Fabric routing through another service that would be requesting the client certificate?

Comment: Adding on some additional information that might be relevant:

The server is hosted in multiple SF clusters across different data centers, and are fronted by a single DNS gateway (maybe not the proper term) that then routes the incoming traffic to the different data centers. The SSL cert CN is the same between all data centers, and the CN on the certificate is the name of the gateway. I'm not sure if there is any change to how SSL would work with a setup like this.

Comment: Any luck solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that "verifyclientcertrevocation=**enable**" is probably causing it to ask for the certificate, regardless of the "clientcertnegotiation=**disable**"

Comment: I tried again with verifyclientcertrevocation=disable and didn't see any change in behavior.